# How big should $k$ be to ensure that $k$ points chosen in a square such that the nearest one to $(a,b)$ is at most $\epsilon$ away?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

So suppose I have a $n \times n$ square, $R$,  on the $x-y$ axis. I generate $k$ random points inside $R$ that are **uniformly** distributed throughout the square. Suppose also that I have another fixed point $(a,b)$ inside $R$.

My question is, how large should $k$ be to ensure that the nearest point (measured by Euclidean distance) from these $k$ generated points is **at most** $\epsilon$ away from $(a,b)$?

Comment: I'm quite curious as to ecactly and rigorously what **uniformly** distributed means ib this context . . .

Comment: You can draw the ball centred at $(a, b)$ with radius $\epsilon$. By uniform assumption you can calculate the probability the a particular point lies within the ball. Then by i.i.d. assumption, the number of points generated to have the first point lies within the ball follows a geometric distribution. If you want to have at least $1$ point inside the ball with probability $\alpha$, then you are asking the $1-\alpha$ quantile of this geometric distribution (somehow you solve the inequality of CDF)

Comment: "ensure" is a big word.  Elsewhere you comment on the expected number of points being at least $1$, which is a much weaker requirement

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a single generated point lie inside the circle around $(a,b)$ of radius $\epsilon$ is, (assuming that the complete circle lies within $n \times n$ square),

$$p_{success} = p = \frac{\pi \epsilon^2}{n^2}$$

Define $X$ as a random variable following geometric distribution with success probability $p$. Here, $X$ represents the number of points that should be generated in order to get a success,

$$P(X=x) = (1-p)^{x-1}p , \ \ x \in \{1, 2, \ldots \}$$

So, the expected number of points will be $E(X) = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{n^2}{\pi \epsilon^2}$

Comment: But there is a finite number of hits so I dont see how this is a geometric distribution? What I mean is, I only have $k$ points so the expected value should also include $k$ as well as $n$ no?

Comment: In other words, I want to know how big $k$ should be such that $E(X)>=1$

Comment: Actually never mind. Thanks for the answer, this answers my question!

Comment: Given a fixed set of $k$ points (independently generated from identical distribution) the probability that atleast one point lies within circle is $1$ minus the probability that no point lie within the circle which equals $1-(1-p)^k$ or the probability of $u$ successes among $k$ points can be modelled using a binomial distribution with parameters $(k,p)$.